# Horizontally align elements shifted by a float

Tags: html, css, alignment

In the following test page there are a video and an iframe elements, both with `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` CSS style.
The video element is shifted toward right by a `float: left;` element containing a few textual lines, therefore it is misaligned with the lower iframe.

I'd like the iframe to be centrally aligned with the video, keeping the video in its current position.

[image]

```
<div style="float: left; border-right: thin solid;">
    A few colored entries here.
</div>


<div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <video src="..."
    style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    </video>
</div>


<iframe src="..." style="width: 300px; height: 100px;
display:block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the whole thing in a wrapper div. Then you can float both divs to the left and still have the insides automatically center.

```
<div id="Wrapper">
    <div class="leftColumn">      
        A few colored entries here.  
    </div>      
    <div class="rightColumn">
        <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">      
            <video src="..."      style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">      </video>  
        </div>      

        <iframe src="..." style="width: 300px; height: 100px;  display:block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">  
        </iframe>  
    </div>
</div>

#Wrapper { overflow: hidden; }
.leftColumn { float: left; border-right: thin solid; width:  200px; }
.rightColumn { float: left; width: 800px; }
```

I didn't test the code, but it should work.

Comment: I'm currently putting the whole thing inside a table, to format it.
However I notice you specify fixed widths for both the columns (200 and 800 px). I can't know the size of their contained elements by the time I write this html; both the video and the text list on the left are generated dynamically and inserted inside this html template during runtime.

Comment: You can use percent or a minimum width (min-width:)

Answer (score 1):

How about putting the two divs that are on the right in their own div, then floating that to the right and using `margin:auto` (like you have currently) to center them.  That way instead of being centered on the page they are centered on the same div, and one shouldn't be pushed farther than the other regardless of the other float.

```
<div style="float: left; border-right: thin solid;">
    A few colored entries here.
</div>

<div style ="float:right;">
<div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <video src="..."
    style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    </video>
</div>



<iframe src="..." style="width: 300px; height: 100px;
display:block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
</iframe>
</div>
```

If I misunderstood and you didn't want to float those to the right, just ignore that and use margins instead.  Either way adding a container div around the ones you want centered together should take care of it.

Comment: Thanks. I bundled the video and the iframe within a basic `div` with no CSS or attributes, but the result is exactly the same.
However, if I add `style="float:right;"` to this `div`, the video and the iframe get horizontally aligned together by their center, which is the wanted result, but both them are pushed to the extreme right, no matter if `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` is applied to this `div`.

Comment: Maybe try using a trick like this? http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/  Either by taking out the float and positioning the new container div that way, or by positioning the divs inside the container with the same method?

Comment: That would work, but the video(s) have unknown size at the time of writing the page's HTML.
Rather, I think the topmost floating `div` on the left could be extended vertically to invisibly occupy all the page height, so whatever stands on its right has the same horizontal limits. But this way the tiny border associated with that `div` (_border-right: thin solid;_) would grow too.